# Transfer text between two Windows 10 computers using IP address (no network shares) without using external programs

Tags: windows-10, networking, data-transfer

Assume one has two Windows 10 computers in a network without Internet access and with network sharing disabled. The machines can ping each other using the IP address of the other machine (no DNS) and all ports are physically available. There is no physical access between the two machines (so no USB stick or similar). Installing new software or enabling disabled software cannot be done (basically making any permanent modifications outside of the user directory cannot be done).

How can text be transmitted between the two computers? In older Windows versions it was possible to use the built-in Telnet client for this purpose, but as it is disabled in Windows 10, this is not a solution.

Comment: What you want is not possible if File Sharing is disabled.  I suppose you could use the built-in capabilities of OpenSSH to transfer the file.  Have you tried that?

Comment: sneakernet?????

Comment: Thanks, but both of the options are not viable. OpenSSH must be explicitly enabled (the requirement is  "enabling disabled software cannot be done"). Sneakernet: "There is no physical access between the two machines"

Comment: If these are corporate machines then speak to your IT department.

Comment: Why the close vote? This is maybe not an usual situation for a home network, but possible and probably interesting.

Comment: @DavidPostill This is not a about a corporate network. If it were, that's of course a valid advice.

Comment: So what access do you have to the two machines? Are you admin on both?

Comment: Why are they so restricted?

Comment: Is this a real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm sure on both sides some PowerShell scripting can do this, but I don't have the opportunity right now to do some digging.

Comment: @DavidPostill It is related to a real problem. I'd rather not sidetrack the discussion with that. It is a problem with clearly defined parameters in the original post. I'm sure it is solvable and would like to tap into the wisdom of this community.

Comment: I don't know if it is solvable. Telnet is gone by default, named pipes are now gone from Windows 10 too.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the text.  You can run for example `waitfor message` then on the other computer you can run `waitfor /SI message`.  This will send a "a message" to the other computer. As other have said, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You call it side tracking, and we call it information necessary to know the context and thus the answer. Right now you've asked us a homework question, it appears. We don't entertain homework questions because your teacher has defined the sources and knowledge you can use. If it's not a homework question we need to know the context in order to understand what is the best answer for you. Give us details, or your question will be closed.